# How to implement timer expire function in sysfs of driver.?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, timer-jobs

**Scenario:** Suppose if I am doing `echo 1 > sysfs_entry` - It will start doing some I/O operation until I do `echo 0 > sysfs_entry`. 
Here, I wanted to implement timer in `sysfs_entry` so that it should stop I/O operation after t seconds , even if I do not give `echo 0 > sysfs_entry`.

**PS:** I do not want to use busy wait methods.

**Preferred:** deferred/delayed work

Please somebody help me to resolve this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `add_timer()` and `del_timer()` API for this. Event queue might also work (depends on context). For more details, please read Chapter 7 «Time, Delays, and Deferred Work» of Linux Device Drivers (aka LDD) book that is available free of charge [right here](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch07.pdf). The Timer API is described on page 198.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. was very helpful. I am looking for a sample in kernel source. I would give answered, once I get it done ;) It will get over by the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer with add_timer() in the write callback of the device driver and make sure to del_timer() or del_timer_sync() in the read callback.